# Symfony 1.4 doctrine simple embed form , not saving the foreign key but added in database

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I m facing a strange behavior, saving an embed form one to one relation is not saving the foreign key

it's a simple register form where I embed the profile form

I created my registering form:

```
class crRegisterForm extends sfGuardRegisterForm{

public function configure()
{
    $this->validatorSchema['first_name']->setOption('required', true);
    $this->validatorSchema['first_name']->setMessage('required', 'pls enter your Firstname');   
    $this->embedRelation('Profile');
}}
```

On my actionClass

```
public function executeRegister(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $this->form = new crRegisterForm();

  if ($request->isMethod('post'))
  {
    $this->form->bind($request->getParameter($this->form->getName()));
    if ($this->form->isValid())
    {
      $user = $this->form->save();
      $user->email_address = $user->username;
      $user->save();
    }
  }
```

This code clearly save a user an a profile on my DataBase but the profile user_id is null ? How come there is no link I though symfony was handling the relation with the 'embedRelation'

Great thanks to all

Comment: Can you post your schema.yml.